# Binding StringFormat doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a DataGrid and an Expander like so:

```
<StackPanel>
<my:DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding}">...</my:DataGrid>
<Expander Header="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.Name, StringFormat=Details of {0}}">...</Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

The binding is fine, but for some reason the string formatting will not work. It always displays only the value dataGrid1.SelectedItem.Name
I have also tried:

```
StringFormat=Details of \{0\}
```

which doesn't work.

I even tried just setting the HeaderStringFormat property of the Expander to "Details of {0}" but that doesn't format it either.

I was able to get this workaround to work though:

```
<Expander>
<Expander.Header>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.Name, StringFormat=Details of {0}}"></TextBox>
</Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

Does anyone know why StringFormat isn't working for the Header property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://codingcontext.wordpress.com/2008/11/17/headerformatstring-and-contentformatstring/, it looks like the `HeaderStringFormat` property isn't meant to be used with string format binding, but rather to specify the format to use when binding to an object that implements `IFormattable`.

Given that, I couldn't get string formatting to work directly in the binding expression, either, so that might just be a bug. You should try notifying Microsoft and maybe they'll fix it.

With your workaround, I would suggest using a `TextBlock` rather than a `TextBox`, since you probably don't want the user to be able to edit the text in the `Expander` header.

Comment: Alright, that's informative. Thanks. Also, I am using a TextBlock...I guess I just wrote it wrong when I made the post.

Answer (score 3):

I've also encountered the same issue and after reading some articles, trying all kinds of [ContentStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [HeaderStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.headerstringformat.aspx) I've just decided to do the next thing:

```
<Expander Grid.Row="1" Padding="4">
                <Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=cbCategory, Path=SelectedItem.CategoryName, StringFormat='FORMATTED &quot;{0}&quot;'}"/>
                </Expander.Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with Header being an Object type property rather than String. The conversion of the String value to a UI control may be interfering with the formatting. Rather than TextBox, does Label work as well? That should give you the same effect as what you were initially trying to do.

**Update**:
Also try looking into the [HeaderStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.headerstringformat.aspx) property.

Comment: You do have a point about Header being an object and TextBox.Text being a string. I just tried with a label, however, and it worked when I set the ContentFormatString to what I wanted. The Label Content property is also an object so I still don't understand...something strange with the Header.